# Where to methods by used by all objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am developing a rails app and I want all my objects to have a certain method that process them. Now, while I realize that I could write that method in each object's model, I would rather stick with the DRY (don't repeat yourself) theory and place the method in one place.

Is there a place I could place a method where all my objects have access to?

Comment: Which objects are you referring to (controllers, models or other)?

Answer (score 3):

Ruby and rails offer a number of options depending on what object you want to have access to a method.

ChiuBaka's answer is one option, however rails in particular offers a number of more readable options.

If you are looking for something on the controller/view level.  You can simply place it in the  `app/helpers/application_helper.rb` file.  If you want to limit access you can create controller specific helper files in the same directory.

If you are looking at models. You can simply create a base model that inherits from `activerecord::base`, implement your method there, and then have your models inherit from that.

```
class MyBase < ActiveModel::Base
  def myinstancemethod
  end

  def myclassmethod
  end
end
```

then

```
class MyModel < MyBase

end
```

then you can call like so

```
instance = MyModel.new
instance.myinstancemethod
```

or

```
MyModel.myclassmethod
```

Answer (score 0):

Place the code you want in all of your models in a module in your /lib folder and require it in your models.